# Unable to access custom data section using customerData.get() inside KnockoutJS component

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.4.2, customer-data

I am following this in order to create new section https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/

All is working if I request '{localhost}/customer/section/load', the custom section 'badges'with data appears there

[image]

Issue is with accessing it using KnockoutJS component. My code is following:

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'ko'
], function ($, Component, customerData, ko) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/template',
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.badges = customerData.get('badges')(); // Returns undefined
            customerData.get('badges').subscribe((badges) => {
                console.log('run badges, run'); // Doesn't executes
                this.badges = badges;
            });
        },

        someAction: function () {
            console.log(this.badges);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try with this

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';
     var sections = ['badges'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
    customerData.reload(sections, true);
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.badges = customerData.get('badges');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I reloaded the customer data ```customerData.reload(['badges'], true);``` before accessing it and it seems to work.